# Interpolation between multiple 2D vector [fields] in a 3D space

Tags: matlab, vector, interpolation, matlab-figure

[image: 7 Pressure-Altitude Layers of 2D Vectors plotted with quiver3]

I've attempted to look at MatLab documentation here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html

and then in the

```
help interp3
```

section of MatLab, but I'm having trouble figuring out what I want actually and if interp3 is the thing that I'm looking for. But, I may just not be understanding if I'm able to use interp3 with the way I have things laid out as of now. I've attached a figure that I can create from a MatLab program that I wrote. It's taking NOAA lat/long (x/y), U/V directions for wind vectors, and then a Z value for the 2D levels to this field.

Using the format:

```
quiver3(x,y,z,u,v,w)
```

with the "W" component set to 0.

This is a very small section of the field, but what I'm trying to do is to interpolate between these 2D vector fields in order to create a 3D field.

Do I have to group U/X , V/Y, and W/Z into their own vectors in order to use interp3 ? I'm still not sure that the 3D function "V" section is in the interp3 syntax of

```
Vq = interp3(X,Y,Z,V,Xq,Yq,Zq)
```

This is a very small section of the field, but what I'm trying to do is to interpolate between these 2D vector fields in order to create a 3D field.

My code:

```
tic
clc
clear all

% You will have to change the directory to wherever you place the read_grib.r4
% file. In addition, It's necessary to have an external compiler connected
% to MatLab in order to build the mex-file that gives you the power to use
% the read_grib decoding. This is really tricky. On OSX I used Xcode as an
% environment and MatLab virtually worked immediately. On Windows, I have
% 2012(b) and had to use the call system('mxvc <BDS_unpack_mex5.c>') which
% utilized Microsoft's C-compiler that I had SOMEWHERE on my computer
% thankfully (may be pre-intalled). There are tutorials online for
% different compilers. In addition, if you're smart about it you can add
% the mex-file build to the start-up operations so you never have to worry
% about it, but my questionably legal MatLab copies seem to make this a
% little more difficult. 

cd /Users/Sargent_PC/Downloads/read_grib.r4/
mex BDS_unpack_mex5.c

% ** Inventory doesn't need to be done every iteration  **
% ** Uncomment the line below to get a record inventory **
%read_grib('NOAAdata.grb','inv');

% Creating a struct named "grib_struct" for each of the records I'm
% extracting out of the grib file. They exist in pairs with 6 records
% separating them. Should we want to extract ALL of the U and V wind
% components I'll iterate with a simple for-loop. 

grib_struct=read_grib('NOAAdata.grb', [60,61,66,67]); %,72,73,78,79,84,85,90,91,96,97]);
UwindVec50mb  = grib_struct(1).fltarray;  %rec60
VwindVec50mb  = grib_struct(2).fltarray;  %rec61
UwindVec75mb  = grib_struct(3).fltarray;  %rec66
VwindVec75mb  = grib_struct(4).fltarray;  %rec67
% UwindVec100mb = grib_struct(5).fltarray;  %rec72
% VwindVec100mb = grib_struct(6).fltarray;  %rec73
% UwindVec125mb = grib_struct(7).fltarray;  %rec78
% VwindVec125mb = grib_struct(8).fltarray;  %rec79
% UwindVec150mb = grib_struct(9).fltarray;  %rec84
% VwindVec150mb = grib_struct(10).fltarray; %rec85
% UwindVec175mb = grib_struct(11).fltarray; %rec90
% VwindVec175mb = grib_struct(12).fltarray; %rec91
% UwindVec200mb = grib_struct(13).fltarray; %rec96
% VwindVec200mb = grib_struct(14).fltarray; %rec97

%50mb  range has records 60 and 61 for U and V respectively.
%75mb  range has records 66 and 67 for U and V respectively.
%100mb range has records 72 and 73 for U and V respectively.
%125mb range has records 78 and 79 for U and V respectively.
%150mb range has records 84 and 85 for U and V respectively.
%175mb range has records 90 and 91 for U and V respectively.
%200mb range has records 96 and 97 for U and V respectively.

%These extracted sections of the grib file will read "extracted" on the
%left-hand side should they be successfully extracted.

load NOAAlatlongdata;                    % read the data into a matrix
lat_value = NOAAlatlongdata(:,3);        %  copy first column of NOAAlatlongdata into lat_value
long_value = NOAAlatlongdata(:,4);       %  and second column of NOAAlatlongdata into long_value


% I was going to add in a pressure to altitude change here, but
% it may be in our best interest to get a list of values for each
% pressure level that correspond to altitude and create our own
% vector of those values in order to simplify the calculations that
% the program has to do. 

% z50mb_val = ;
% z75mb_val = ;
% z100mb_val= ;
% z125mb_val= ;
% z150mb_val= ;
% z175mb_val= ; 
% z200mb_val= ;

% Creating vectors of the Z-values which are gotten from converting the
% pressure value to altitude. I feel like this is a very bulky way to do
% this, and I've included the tic-toc timing to show that it's ~30seconds
% per vector creation. For each altitude level that we add you'll add
% ~30seconds JUST to the vector creation component of the program. 

tic; for i = 1:262792, z50mb_vec=67507*ones(i,1);  end; toc;

tic; for i = 1:262792, z75mb_vec=60296*ones(i,1);  end; toc; 

% tic; for i = 1:262792, z100mb_vec=53084*ones(i,1); end; toc; 
% 
% tic; for i = 1:262792, z125mb_vec=48865*ones(i,1); end; toc;
% 
% tic; for i = 1:262792, z150mb_vec=44646*ones(i,1); end; toc;
% 
% tic; for i = 1:262792, z175mb_vec=43763*ones(i,1);  end; toc;
% 
% tic; for i = 1:262792, z200mb_vec=38661*ones(i,1); end; toc;
% 
 tic; for i = 1:262792, W_zerovec = 0*ones(i,1);    end; toc; 
% 

% 3D quiver plots format: quiver3(x,y,z,u,v,w) -- Make sure dimensionality
% of all 6 components to that plot match up before plotting.

quiver3((lat_value(1:101)), (long_value(1:25)), ( z50mb_vec(1:25)), (UwindVec50mb(1:25)) ,(VwindVec50mb(1:25)) , W_zerovec(1:25)) 
hold on
quiver3((lat_value(1:101)), (long_value(1:251)), ( z75mb_vec(1:25)), (UwindVec75mb(1:25)) ,(VwindVec75mb(1:25)) , W_zerovec(1:25))
hold on
% quiver3((lat_value(1:101)), (long_value(1:101)), (z100mb_vec(1:101)), (UwindVec100mb(1:101)),(VwindVec100mb(1:101)), W_zerovec(1:101))
% hold on
% quiver3((lat_value(1:101)), (long_value(1:101)), (z125mb_vec(1:101)), (UwindVec125mb(1:101)),(VwindVec125mb(1:101)), W_zerovec(1:101))
% hold on
% quiver3((lat_value(1:101)), (long_value(1:101)), (z150mb_vec(1:101)), (UwindVec150mb(1:101)),(VwindVec150mb(1:101)), W_zerovec(1:101))
% hold on
% quiver3((lat_value(1:101)), (long_value(1:101)), (z175mb_vec(1:101)), (UwindVec175mb(1:101)),(VwindVec175mb(1:101)), W_zerovec(1:101))
% hold on
% quiver3((lat_value(1:101)), (long_value(1:101)), (z200mb_vec(1:101)), (UwindVec200mb(1:101)),(VwindVec200mb(1:101)), W_zerovec(1:101))

toc
```

Comment: How are your 2D fields structured? Are they each on the same X-Y regular grid and only the Z values change?

Comment: Sorry to get back to you so late. They are the same lat/long - x/y values for the same section in the field. Think of it as trying to plot multiple layers of the same field. Z is the pressure-altitude, so that's going to vary with interpolation, U and X will vary between the layers at the same x/y (lat/long) values, and W will stay constant at zero (not provided with W-component). So basically if I can selectively interpolate between the U and V components of the vector across a range of Z ( in this case the distance in between levels), then I will fill in the 3D space like I'm looking to do.

Comment: Couldn't edit above: U and V components will vary between the layers at the same x/y lat/long values, not U and X, sorry for confusion!And I'm trying to fill in the gaps between multiple 2D sheets through a linear interpolation, just for clarification.

Comment: Have you tried interpolating each component independantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guy by the name of Failmond is provided me with this, which suitably solves my query! Thanks to all!

```
zLevels = 5;   %number of interpolated points between z50 and z75
nStation = 100;     %number of (lat,long) pairs to interpolate
for i = 1:nStation %for nStation different (lat, long) pairs generate interp. values
        % generate zQuery points between z50 and z75 for each station
        zQuery = ((1:zLevels)/zLevels)*range([z50mb_vec(i) z75mb_vec(i)]) + z75mb_vec(i);
        % use interp1 to interpolate about the Z axis for U component
        U(i,1:N) = interp1([z50mb_vec(i) z75mb_vec(i)],[UwindVec50mb(i) UwindVec75mb(i)],zQuery);
        % and for V component
        V(i,1:N) = interp1([z50mb_vec(i) z75mb_vec(i)],[VwindVec50mb(i) VwindVec75mb(i)],zQuery);
end

% defining some color codes for each zLevel, otherwise the plot is a mess
% of colors
colorcode = ['r' 'g' 'b' 'm' 'c' 'r' 'g' 'b' 'm' 'c' 'r'];
for j = 1:nStation
    for i = 1:zLevels
    quiver3(lat_value(j), long_value(j), zQuery(i), U(j,i), V(j,i), 0, colorcode(i));
    hold on;
    end
end
```